# Async await database taking time

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, async-await

In my case, I need to load some data from database at the beginning of the application. But I cannot load data, so I tested what is wrong with my code and found out it takes some time in `await database` and the code skip this function and execute other operations. In result , I get the data later after creating the UI, so cannot show data. Any way to fix that?
 This is my code and result-

dbhelper.dart

```
    static Database db_instance;

      Future<Database> get db async{
        if(db_instance == null)
        db_instance = await initDB();
        return db_instance;
      }

      initDB() async{
        var dbDir = await getDatabasesPath();
        var dbPath = join(dbDir, "test.db");
        ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets","test.db"));
        List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
        await File(dbPath).writeAsBytes(bytes);

        var db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
        return db;
      }

    getTest() async{
     print("Test1");
     var db_connection = await db;
     print("Test2");
     List<Map> list = await db_connection.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME Where id= 1');
     print("Test3");
     for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
       print("Test4");
       id = list[i]['id'];
       name = list[i]['name'];
       phone = list[i]['phone'];
      }
     print("Test5"+name);
   }
```

main.dart

```
getContactsFromDB()async{
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  dbHelper.getTest();
  print("Test6"+phone);
}

@override
  void initState()  {
    getContactsFromDB();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Result

```
I/flutter (13203): Test1
I/flutter (13203): Test6 // skip Test2,3,4,5 and jump to another operation and data not collected
I/flutter (13203): Test2
I/flutter (13203): Test3
I/flutter (13203): Test4
I/flutter (13203): Test5 Zin
```

Comment: try to use future builder, so the UI will be rendered after the future builder function completed

Comment: Future Builder works for me thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use FutureBuilder. Something like here:

```
Widget projectWidget() {
   return FutureBuilder(
     future: getContactsFromDB(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
           return Container();
       } else {
           return CircularProgressIndicator();
       }
    }
  ) 
}
```